# Delete gmails with script using google sheet with gmail search terms and multiple rows in sheet for bulk processing

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, automation, gmail

This function will delete ONE (1) email matching search term defined in A2 (And it works):

```
function deleteEmail() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  const searchTerm = sheet.getRange("A2").getValue();
  GmailApp.search(searchTerm).map(thread => thread.moveToTrash()); 
}
```

However, creating individual script functions for individual search terms with individual triggers would take forever to do...

I tried simply to use A2:A, but unfortunately that was not working.

```
function deleteEmail() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  const searchTerm = sheet.getRange("A2:A").getValue();
  GmailApp.search(searchTerm).map(thread => thread.moveToTrash()); 
}
```

How can one delete gmails with a script using google sheet scripts with gmail search terms and multiple rows in a sheet for bulk processing?

3 parameters are needed: sender, subject and older_than, like this:

from:(@google.com) subject:Notification older_than:3d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Perhaps this will work

```
function deleteEmail() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  const terms = sheet.getRange("A2:A" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  terms.forEach(s => GmailApp.search(s).forEach(thread => thread.moveToTrash()))
}
```

Comment: I see the idea, but I got this Error 
ReferenceError: Gmail is not defined

Comment: That was supposed to be GmailApp